# Unable to open FilePicker with Google App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-picker

I was trying to use Google App Script. My first attempt concern the capability to open a file picker and select a file from my Google Drive. To do this, I read th [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker) and I try to implement it. So I write the following application:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      /*.createTemplateFromFile('index.html')
      .evaluate();*/
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html');
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // The Browser API key obtained from the Google API Console.
    // Replace with your own Browser API key, or your own key.
    var developerKey = "{{developer-key}}";                        

    // The Client ID obtained from the Google API Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
    var clientId = "{{client-id}}"

    // Replace with your own project number from console.developers.google.com.
    // See "Project number" under "IAM & Admin" > "Settings"
    var appId = "{{project-number}}";

    // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
    var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;
    var oauthToken;

    // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
    function loadPicker() {
      gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
    }

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
      window.gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
          },
          handleAuthResult);
    }

    function onPickerApiLoad() {
      pickerApiLoaded = true;
      createPicker();
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
      }
    }

    // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
    function createPicker() {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()            
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView()) 
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
         picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

    // A simple callback implementation.
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
        alert('The user selected: ' + fileId);
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to execute the code, after the authorization phase, I obtain the a blank screen and a blank dialog with the error: Failed to execute 'postMessage'. What is wrong? Thanks

[image: screenshot]

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue/Solution:

You're working within a `iframe`, where content is served from a different origin. You should use `setOrigin` on the picker builder.

#### Snippet:

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
   //...
  .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
```

#### Reference:

- [Working with Picker API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe#picker_api_change)
- [File Open Dialog Code Sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs)